# ImportError using Django on linux: No module named dal

Tags: python, linux, django

I recently switched from using mac to using linux, and I've had to move my code base over. In the process, my Django app has stopped working -- the issue seems to be an ImportError, where I don't have the module named dal.

```
python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f1335da6d70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named dal
```

I've had a look, but can't seem to find this issue elsewhere, so hoping that someone else might be able to help me out in fixing this!

Thanks!

Comment: nope, I'm using 2.7.11

Comment: Can you paste your *settings.py*. I suspect that you've got something weird in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: oops yes, I had used django-autocomplete-light and forgot that I needed to install that. That requires dal to function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This dependency should be missing in your environment. Add it by:

```
pip install dal
```

Answer (score 1):

dal means **django-autocomplete-light**.

To install it with `pip` you should execute `pip install django-autocomplete-light`. Hope it helps